# Where to validate DTO

Tags: validation, language-agnostic, dto

I am writing a Webservice which sends and receives DTO's

A DTO might look like this(in this example its C#)

```
[Serializable]
public class GetCardStatusRequest : RequestBase
{
    public GetCardStatusRequest()
    {

    }

    public String CardId { get; set; }
}
```

when receiving such a request DTO I want to validate that the CardId is for example not empty.

So I currently have a validation class

```
internal class Validation
{
    internal static bool IsValidGetGiftCardStatusRequest(GetCardStatusRequest getCardStatusRequest)
    {
        return getCardStatusRequest.CardId != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(getCardStatusRequest.CardId);
    }
}
```

There are more "complex" DTO's so I wanted to place the validation logic somewhere to ensure that the incoming requests are valid before mapping them to the business objects.

My question is where should I place the validation logic and how should I do it ? I currently have this class with only static methods which seem wrong to me.
Should this validation be placed in the service layer ? 
I feel quite close with this logic above, but nevertheless it seems not correct.